# Problem to run rspec test on my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

when I use command spec path/to/spec_file.rb then it come with the message below. I am not sure what wrong with my RSpec or with my ROR since I use RVM(Rail 3 and Ruby 1.9.2)

```
/var/www/resource_mapper_spike/config/boot.rb:3: uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE (NameError)
from /var/www/resource_mapper_spike/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
from /var/www/resource_mapper_spike/config/application.rb:1
from /var/www/resource_mapper_spike/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
from /var/www/resource_mapper_spike/config/environment.rb:2
from /var/www/resource_mapper_spike/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
from /var/www/resource_mapper_spike/spec/spec_helper.rb:3
from ./spec/models/layer_spec.rb:1:in `require'
from ./spec/models/layer_spec.rb:1
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load_files'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/options.rb:134:in `run_examples'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
from /usr/bin/spec:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found problem with my command. spec command could run only on rails 2 but in rails 3 I have to use command rspec